# mscorlib: TypeError: context.res is not a function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am writing a a NodeJS function for Azure Functions. However, when trying to call `context.res` to return a response to the caller, the function fails with the following exception:

```
2016-06-26T07:45:59.171 Exception while executing function: Functions.getSASToken. mscorlib: TypeError: context.res is not a function
    at module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\getSASToken\index.js:63:26)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\0.2.10238\bin\edge\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:42:7).
```

Contents of the `function.json` file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "webHookType": "",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "authLevel": "anonymous"
    },
    {
      "name": "res",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

And the function in question:

```
module.exports = function(context, req) { 
    var token = req.query.token;
    var deviceId = req.query.deviceId;

    var resourceUri = util.format('%s/devices/%s', sbNamespace, deviceId);

    var sasToken = generateSasToken(resourceUri, token, null, 14400);

    context.res({
        status: 200,
        body: sasToken
    });

    context.done();
}
```

Iterating through the `context.bindings` object shows that it only contains the property `req` (`res` is entirely missing).

FYI, overriding the response object via `context.done(null, {res: {status:200, body: sasToken}}` does return the desired output to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
context.res({
    status: 200,
    body: sasToken
});
```

You need

```
context.res = {
    status: 200,
    body: sasToken
};
```

Comment: I knew it had to be a straightforward syntax error :-) thanks for the pointer.